# C# way to add item in specific position

Tags: c#

I have string array which contains data like,

```
string[] temp = new();
temp[0] = "abc";
temp[1] = "mno";
temp[2] = "xyz";
```

I need the output like,
i need store value in specific variable

ex,

```
string value1 = "abc";
string value2 = "mno xyz"
```

so in another string i want the combine data of index 1 and 2.

Comment: how do you assign value to string variables?  `string value2 = $"{temp[1]} {temp[2]}"; like this?

Comment: yes i need that value in string variable so passed it like
value1 = temp[0];

But my point is i don't know how many index is there in array
and i need to combine rest of index in another string variable after 0 index

Comment: You need to explain this in the question. It is not clear what is your expectation and what issue you are facing. What do you expect to happen if the list has only 1 value or only 2 value? or more than 3 value?

Comment: If the list has more than 3 values, what's the problem with doing `string value2 = $"{temp[1]} {temp[2]}";` ?

Comment: Please don't put pseudo-C# - put real code.

Comment: `string string2 = string.Join(' ', temp[1..]);`

Comment: Also, don't edit the question in a way that invalidates existing answers. Add to your question, rather than change it. And let those that have answered follow suit. It just gets confusing otherwise.

Comment: @meha I rolled back your changes because a question should not be changed in a way that invalidates existing answer(s). You can post a new question in that case.

Comment: _"It just gets confusing otherwise."_ ^^ and people late to the party may downvote answers because they no longer answer the question :(

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you said in a comment, *"But my point is i don't know how many index is there in array"*. Isn't that what the `.Length` property tells us? Can you clarify please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string[] temp = new string[] { "abc", "mno", "xyz" };
string value1 = temp[0];
string value2 = string.Join(" ", temp.Skip(1));
Console.WriteLine("value1 = " + value1);
Console.WriteLine("value2 = " + value2);
```

The Skip(1) method is used to skip the first element (i.e., "abc") and return the remaining elements as an IEnumerable. Then, the string.Join() method is used to join the elements with a space separator, resulting in the string "mno xyz". Finally, the value1 and value2 variables are assigned the appropriate values, and their values are printed to the console.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `String.Format();`

In your case it would look like this:

```cs
string value2 = String.Format("{0} {1}", temp[1], temp[2]);

// Another way of doing this:
string value2 = $"{temp[1]} {temp[2]}";
```

You can read more about it here: [String.Format() Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-7.0)

---

If you want to join all items of the array into the string you can use:

```cs
string allElementsCombined = String.Join(' ', temp);
```

This will combine all strings from `temp` and add space character between them.

You can read more about this here: [String.Join() Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-7.0)

Comment: I assume you didn't mean to use `.Concat`?

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes, pardon. I corrected my answer. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 2):

Just add all string you want

```
string sum = temp[1] + " " + temp[2];
```

> To concatenate string variables, you can use the + or += operators, string interpolation or the String.Format, String.Concat, String.Join or StringBuilder.Append methods. The + operator is easy to use and makes for intuitive code. Even if you use several + operators in one statement, the string content is copied only once

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/concatenate-multiple-strings

Answer (score 2):

To combine array values into a string you can simply do the following:

```
string[] temp = new();
temp[0] = "abc";
temp[1] = "mno";
temp[2] = "xyz";

string value1 = temp[0];
string value2 = String.Format("{0} {1}",temp[1], temp[2]);
```

Comment: Side note: *string interpolation* `string value2 = $"{temp[1]} {temp[2]}";` can be more readable than `Format`